# PYTHON 2.7 - Parsing oddly structured JSON file

Tags: json, python-2.7, parsing, dataframe

I've currently got a JSON file that 've tried several methods of importing into python 2.7.

This is my data:

```
[["195b95d248e5478485bfdff82ed7504a", {"attributes": {"checkin_payment_rate": {"N": "10"}, "dateBooked": {"S": "2015-11-03"}, "dateCheckin": {"S": "2015-11-03T15:41:40.126034+0000"}, "date_created": {"S": "2015-11-03T15:41:29.546868+0000"}, "spaceID": {"S": "67dcfcf3fafe4cde9e50069cdbff2314"}, "stripe_transferID": {"S": "tr_1736umJLCycAnsZaf52drYC0"}, "userID": {"S": "b0c096530f464c1fb2cba8ed5470bbc6"}}}], ["413b1dfe841c4f95b2169da369179cd1", {"attributes": {"checkin_payment_rate": {"N": "10"}, "dateBooked": {"S": "2015-09-11"}, "dateCheckin": {"S": "2015-09-11T20:22:40.218580+0000"}, "date_created": {"S": "2015-09-11T18:39:33.374925+0000"}, "spaceID": {"S": "8c85543487ba49dd816f9b1eceafd3ca"}, "stripe_transferID": {"S": "tr_16jy2eJLCycAnsZatj0aVWyB"}, "userID": {"S": "38522c00725245f58f58cca01a8b62c7"}}}],
```

Which...as you can see... is just one big ass line.

Here is what the code looks like when I run a simple load command and pprint.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
from pprint import pprint


with open('example.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)


pprint(data)
```

This is the result

```
[[u'195b95d248e5478485bfdff82ed7504a',
  {u'attributes': {u'checkin_payment_rate': {u'N': u'10'},
               u'dateBooked': {u'S': u'2015-09-03'},
               u'dateCheckin': {u'S': u'2015-11-03T15:41:40.126034+0000'},
               u'date_created': {u'S': u'2015-11-03T15:41:29.546868+0000'},
               u'spaceID': {u'S': u'67dcfcf3fafe4cde9e50069cdbff2314'},
               u'stripe_transferID': {u'S': u'hr_9876umJLCycAnsZaf52drYC0'},
               u'userID': {u'S': u'c9df86530f464c1fb2cba8ed5470bbc6'}}}],
 [u'413b1dfe841c4f95b2169da369179cd1',
  {u'attributes': {u'checkin_payment_rate': {u'N': u'10'},
               u'dateBooked': {u'S': u'2015-04-11'},
               u'dateCheckin': {u'S': u'2015-09-11T20:22:40.218580+0000'},
               u'date_created': {u'S': u'2015-09-11T18:39:33.374925+0000'},
               u'spaceID': {u'S': u'8c85543487ba49dd816f9b1eceafd3ca'},
               u'stripe_transferID': {u'S': u'gr_76jy2eJLCycAnsZatj0aVWyB'},
               u'userID': {u'S': u'36536c00725245f58f58cca01a8b62c7'}}}],
```

My goal is to get this data into a nice, orderly dataframe that has a column for the overarching ID (In the first case [[u'195b95d248e5478485bfdff82ed7504a') with separate columns for each of the attributes on the same row.

I've tried

```
test1 = pd.read_json("example.json","records","frame")
```

which gave me this:

```
                                     0  \                                                      
0     195b95d248e5478485bfdff82ed7504a   
1     413b1dfe841c4f95b2169da369179cd1   
                                                  1  
0     {u'attributes': {u'stripe_transferID': {u'S': ...  
1     {u'attributes': {u'stripe_transferID': {u'S': ...
```

which turned out nicely in that it gave me a column of the overaching IDS next to a column of attributes... but all the attributes for that ID were lumped together in the 2nd column.

I also tried the pandas normalization option below:

`test2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,'attributes',['stripe_transferID','dateCheckin','userID','spaceID','date_created','dateBooked','checkin_payment_rate','N'])`

but I keep getting the error `list indices must be integers, not str`

Any thoughts on how I can either break up the 2nd column into individual columns in test1 or make test2 work? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your exact situation, but in case every element structure is always identical you could use basic Python objects to achieve the exact output you are after, in this case load your data as a string, I just copied paste your example, fix brackets to make it look like a popper element, in this case add a ']' at the end to make it look like a list and use ast to make it an actual list:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

l =    '''[["195b95d248e5478485bfdff82ed7504a", {"attributes":{"checkin_payment_rate": {"N": "10"}, 
    "dateBooked": {"S": "2015-11-03"}, "dateCheckin": {"S": "2015-11-03T15:41:40.126034+0000"},
    "date_created": {"S": "2015-11-03T15:41:29.546868+0000"}, "spaceID": {"S": "67dcfcf3fafe4cde9e50069cdbff2314"},
    "stripe_transferID": {"S": "tr_1736umJLCycAnsZaf52drYC0"}, "userID": {"S": "b0c096530f464c1fb2cba8ed5470bbc6"}}}],
   ["413b1dfe841c4f95b2169da369179cd1", {"attributes": {"checkin_payment_rate": {"N": "10"}, 
    "dateBooked": {"S": "2015-09-11"}, "dateCheckin": {"S": "2015-09-11T20:22:40.218580+0000"}, 
    "date_created": {"S": "2015-09-11T18:39:33.374925+0000"}, "spaceID": {"S": "8c85543487ba49dd816f9b1eceafd3ca"}, "stripe_transferID": 
    {"S": "tr_16jy2eJLCycAnsZatj0aVWyB"}, "userID": {"S": "38522c00725245f58f58cca01a8b62c7"}}}]]'''

data = ast.literal_eval(l)
```

From here on it is just python, create a custom function:

```
def Parse(e):
    dic = {k:v.values()[0] for (k,v)  in e[1]['attributes'].items()}     #lose the S and N indicators
    dic['id'] = e[0] #get the ID 
    return dic
```

Apply it to every element:

```
pd.DataFrame([Parse(e) for e in data])
```

You should get this (hopefully what you were looking for):

[image: partial output]

Note that the column order is alphabetical since it came from a dict.

Comment: My god thank you so much Ezer this works perfectly! I'd been trying to figure this out for the better part of 3 days now. As if that wasn't indicative of my freshness to Python, could I trouble you to explain what is going on inside of your custom function? I'm having a lot of trouble understanding exactly what is happening in your magic. Thank you so much!!

Comment: happy to help. to understand the function you mainly have to know what 'dict comprehension' is, look it up (it is list comprehension for dicts). At any rate, the function basically does 2 things to any element (list) of your data and wraps it up back to a simple key:value dict: 1. takes the second part of the element which is a dict where every value is a dict of it's own and keeps only the values of the inner dicts, this is what the dict comprehension is for, 2. once you have a nice simple dic of the second part of the element you just add to it the id from the first part of the element.